# Sitecore Filter Pages based on Parent of Parent Page

Tags: c#, sitecore

**My Page Structure**

-Career Page 1  (Template-Generic Page)

- Front End Developer (Normal Folder)

  - Page1   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page2   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page3   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page4   (Template-Job Page)
- Back End Developer (Normal Folder)

  - Page1   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page2   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page3   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page4   (Template-Job Page)

-Career Page 2  (Template-Generic Page)

- Front End Developer (Normal Folder)

  - Page1   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page2   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page3   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page4   (Template-Job Page)
- Back End Developer (Normal Folder)

  - Page1   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page2   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page3   (Template-Job Page)
  - Page4   (Template-Job Page)

My Question is: I have coded in such a way that whenever I hit (Career Page 1)
I get the List of Pages which uses a Job page Template
So I get List of Page 1-8 of Career Page 1 and List of Page 1-8 Career Page 2
but I want only Pages of (Career Page 1)

I have tried GetQueryable to get the list of Pages where template id is equal to Job Page Template

IQueryable search = context.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.TemplateId == PageID); //This will Get me the list all pages created from PageID(Job page) template

I want Pages only of (Career Page 1) when I hit Career Page 1 and List of Pages only of (Career Page 2) when I hit Career Page 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter on `Paths` (indexed as `_path`) as well. It contains a list of `ID`'s representing the path where the items are located. So it would look something like this (depending on what your model looks like):

```
contex.GetQueryable<MyType>().Where(x => x.TemplateId == JobPageTemplateId && x.Paths.Contains(careerPageId))
```

Depending on what your solution looks like, consider filtering on language and `_latestversion` as well to avoid unexpected results and potential duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can be filtered using multiple way

1. Use Axes.GetAncestors to get the list of Ancestors and run a loop to Page type contains that Ancestor or not
2. Use Path attribute to check if Career page Name{Attribute} is present or not, this can be done by this was Jobpage.Path.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Item.Name)